# Should I take advice from an AI CV checker when preparing a postdoc application?

Tags: application, postdocs, career-path, cv

I am near the end of my PhD and intending to apply for academic jobs, especially post-doc research positions.

One of the services offered by our university to its postgraduate researchers (PhD students) is an "AI"-driven CV checking tool.  In fact, they ask that you get your CV up to at least a 70% rating from the automated tool before booking an appointment with them to discuss your CV/application.

The issue I have is that it feels like cv-by-numbers and also a bit silly or limited, e.g. telling me off for being inconsistent with dates, but the only offending date is part of a sentence rather than a table heading.

Is there not a danger that following these rules leads to boring CVs; or even CVs that are obviously edited using this kind of rigid tool?  Am I being naive, are academic recruiters really taken in by me "re-phrasing a responsibility as an action"?  As an imposter-syndrome-affected postgrad (I know I'm not alone) I'm obviously not great at self-promotion.

This tool is (according to the company's web site) used by other good universities too, and I can see some moderate benefit from achieving consistency and checking for some obvious no-nos.  I wonder if this sort of stuff is more applicable to applying for jobs in industry where there may be 1000s of applicants and automated screening.

Of course I want my CV to put me in the best possible light and to give an accurate account of my experiences and competencies - should I follow the "advice" given by this tool?  I'm asking especially as it seems to be a pre-requisite to accessing actual human help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a complaint presented as a question.

Comment: I think you've already figured out the answer:  "No."  That said, CVs should be boring and they do not use pronouns.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I can't really argue with you there, I was quite complainy.  I think I do have a genuine question, which is ... "is this sort of advice applicable to academic applications, or is it more suited to students who are looking to apply in industry where they may face 1000s of applicants per post". I'll try to rephrase.

Comment: CVs are, and should be, formulaic - they are meant to convey certain information in a concise and consistent way that is easy for the recipient to parse. Will an automated checker provide 100% accurate warnings? No, but neither does a compiler - you use your intelligence to figure out the right thing to do.

Comment: Keep in mind that a similar AI might be used in screening your application...

Comment: Here’s some advice from a human: your question is long and difficult to read, and it’s not clear what you’re asking exactly. Extrapolating from this to your CV, I’d speculate that it also needs to be made clearer and less verbose. But if I had to guess whether it’s likely that an AI assistant will help you, my guess would be “no”. Stick with the humans (who are familiar with the academic job market) is my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you "consider" the generated advice pretty much as you would any advice, but with an extra dose of skepticism. Some things suggested by an AI are probably valid, more or less, but you get bone-headed (silicon-headed?) advice in many cases.

So, make a judgement. If it seems reasonable, then try it. Otherwise not. But your sense that it might seem "stilted" if taken too far is probably correct. A machine generated CV is unlikely to stand out from the crowd, though the content should be more important than the form.

You might also have a faculty member at the institution take a look and give some more human (humane?) advice.

Comment: If the question asks for an answer that makes a judgement, recommending making a judgement is not a helpful answer.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, yes, thanks. Fixed. Words escape me. Literally.